# How to return untranslated keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, localization, ruby-on-rails-4

For an API, I want to return the actual keyified string.

So:

```
User.errors.messages[:name]
#=> activerecord.errors.models.user.attrributes.blank
```

Instead of

```
 Can't be blank
```

I know I can override this by creating an actual translation, or by setting custom errors in the `validates` methods in my Models, but I was wondering if there is a lower level, simpler way to make rails return the "keyified" string instead of parsing it through the translation-layers.

Answer (score 0):

I answered some similar questions on SO, but could not find them right now...

I think that this is not possible right now because the [ActiveModel::Errors::add](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8c9498140e3ddecd9afef2df99ecf6ab25437f63/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb#L291) method does not store the Key to the message, but just the derived message.

It's also not trivial to reverse get the key from translation files or the like.

I think it would be a valuable addition to rails to actually store the key of the error-message instead of just the message itself.